# SwiftUIにてPHPickerを用いた際に、PHPickerを開いたTabに戻りたいのだが、初期のTabView画面に戻ってしまう。

Tags: swift, swiftui, swift5

TabViewの子ビュー内にてPHPickerを使用し、PHPicker使用後に元々開いていた子ビューではなく、TabView内のStateで指定している最初のTabに戻ってしまいます。

PHPickerを閉じる際には、下記コードのようにdismissを用いて画面を閉じる操作をしており、どのようにしたら元の画面に戻れるのかを模索しています。

お分かりになる方がいれば、ご教示くださいませ。

ContentView:

```
struct ContentView: View {

enum Tabs: String {
    case tab1 = "FirstView"
    case tab2 = "SecondView"
    case tab3 = "アカウント"
}

func returnNavigationTitle(tabSelection: Tabs) -> String {
    switch tabSelection {
    case .tab1:
        return "FirstView"
    case .tab2:
        return "SecondView"
    case .tab3:
        return "アカウント"
    }
}

@State private var navigationTitle: String = Tabs.tab1.rawValue
@State var tabSelection: Tabs = .tab1

var body: some View {
    TabView(selection: $tabSelection) {
        FirstView()
            .tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "house.fill")
                Text(Tabs.tab1.rawValue)
            }.tag(1)//.tabItem
        SecondView()
            .tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "list.bullet")
                Text(Tabs.tab2.rawValue)
            }.tag(2)//.tabItem
        PhotoPickerView()
            .tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "person.circle")
                Text(Tabs.tab3.rawValue)
            }.tag(3)//.tabItem
    }.accentColor(.blue)
}
```

ImagePicker:

```
struct ImagePicker: UIViewControllerRepresentable {

@Environment(\.presentationMode) private var presentationMode
var sourceType: UIImagePickerController.SourceType = .photoLibrary
@Binding var selectedImage: UIImage

func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ImagePicker>) -> UIImagePickerController {
    
    let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
    imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
    imagePicker.sourceType = sourceType
    imagePicker.delegate = context.coordinator
    
    return imagePicker
}

func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIImagePickerController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ImagePicker>) {
    
}

func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
    Coordinator(self)
}

final class Coordinator: NSObject, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    
    var parent: ImagePicker
    
    init(_ parent: ImagePicker) {
        self.parent = parent
    }
    
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        
        if let image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage {
            parent.selectedImage = image
        }
        
        parent.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
    }
    
}
```

PhotoPickerView:

```
struct PhotoPickerView: View {

@State private var isShowingPhotoPicker = false
@State private var avaterImage = UIImage(named: "default-avatar")!

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Image(uiImage: avaterImage)
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFit()
            .frame(width: 150, height: 150)
            .clipShape(Circle())
            .padding()
            .onTapGesture {
                isShowingPhotoPicker = true
            }
        
        Spacer()
    }
    .navigationTitle("Profile")
    .sheet(isPresented: $isShowingPhotoPicker, content: {
        ImagePicker(sourceType: .photoLibrary, selectedImage: self.$avaterImage)
        //PhotoPicker(avaterImage: $avaterImage)
    })
}
```

開発環境：
Xcode 13.3
Swift 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tagの設定が間違っています。
TabViewのselectionと.tag()の型は揃えないといけません。

```swift
.tag(Tabs.tab1)
```